# How to create a java Server that accepts client connections and then build a relay connection for a client pair

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I want to create a server that can accept multiple connections and then bind 2 clients as a pair and forward the data between these 2 clients. But it is about multiple pairs of clients. I already have multithread server that can create a new thread for each new connected client. The problem for me is that these threads dont know of each other and somehow I have to connect 2 clients to a connection pair.

For now I just create these pair connection as this: I wait for the first client, then I wait for the second client and then open a thread for the input of client 1 that gets forwarded to client 2 and the other way around. This is not usable for multiple clients.

How can I do this decent?

Comment: I guess You would have to somehow identify each client, wouldn't You?

Comment: Yes I know what client pair to connect because they have to send a unique ID after they connected to the server. My "problem" is if I open a thread for each client and wait for the input stream, how can I connect those two clients that are handled in different threads?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, a client would need to

1. establish a TCP(?) connection with your server,
2. identify itself
3. give the ID of the other client it wishes to talk to

The first that connects would have to be kept on hold (in some global table in your server) until the second client connects.
Once a pair of clients would have been recognized as interlocutors, you would create a pair of threads to forward the data sent by each client to the other one.

UPDATE: Example

ClientSocket.java

```
package matchmaker;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientSocket implements Closeable {
    private final Socket socket;
    private final InputStream in;
    private final OutputStream out;
    private final String ownId;
    private final String peerId;

    public ClientSocket(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.in = socket.getInputStream();
        this.out = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
        this.ownId = din.readUTF();
        this.peerId = din.readUTF();
    }

    public ClientSocket(String server, int port, String ownId, String peerId)
            throws IOException {
        this.socket = new Socket(server, port);
        this.socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        this.in = socket.getInputStream();
        this.out = socket.getOutputStream();
        this.ownId = ownId;
        this.peerId = peerId;
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
        dout.writeUTF(ownId);
        dout.writeUTF(peerId);
    }

    public String getOwnId() {
        return ownId;
    }

    public String getPeerId() {
        return peerId;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return in;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return out;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Matchmaker.java: the server

```
package matchmaker;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Matchmaker extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOG
            = Logger.getLogger(Matchmaker.class.getName());

    private final int port;
    private final Map<ClientPair,ClientSocket> waiting = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = 1234;
            int st = 0;
            for (String arg: args) {
                switch (st) {
                    case 0:
                        switch (arg) {
                            case "-p":
                                st = 1;
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Unknown option: " + arg);
                                return;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        port = Integer.parseInt(arg);
                        st = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            Matchmaker server = new Matchmaker(port);
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private Matchmaker(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                ClientSocket socket = new ClientSocket(server.accept());
                ClientPair pair = new ClientPair(
                        socket.getOwnId(), socket.getPeerId());
                ClientSocket other;
                synchronized(this) {
                    other = waiting.remove(pair.opposite());
                    if (other == null) {
                        waiting.put(pair, socket);
                    }
                }
                if (other != null) {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Establishing connection for {0}",
                            pair);
                    establishConnection(socket, other);
                } else {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Waiting for counterpart {0}", pair);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void establishConnection(ClientSocket socket, ClientSocket other)
            throws IOException {
        Thread thread = new StreamCopier(
                socket.getInputStream(), other.getOutputStream());
        thread.start();
        thread = new StreamCopier(
                other.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

StreamCopier.java: a thread that reads from an InputStream and writes to an OutputStream

```
package matchmaker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class StreamCopier extends Thread {
    private static final Logger LOG
            = Logger.getLogger(StreamCopier.class.getName());

    private final InputStream in;
    private final OutputStream out;

    public StreamCopier(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Start stream copier");
        try {
            for (int b = in.read(); b != -1; b = in.read()) {
                out.write(b);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            LOG.info("End stream copier");
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientPair.java: a pair of client IDs

```
package matchmaker;

public class ClientPair {
    private final String client1;
    private final String client2;

    public ClientPair(String client1, String client2) {
        this.client1 = client1;
        this.client2 = client2;
    }

    public String getClient1() {
        return client1;
    }

    public String getClient2() {
        return client2;
    }

    public ClientPair opposite() {
        return new ClientPair(client2, client1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 73 * hash + client1.hashCode();
        hash = 73 * hash + client2.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ClientPair other = (ClientPair) obj;
        return client1.equals(other.client1) && client2.equals(other.client2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + client1 + "," + client2 + "]";
    }
}
```

ReaderClient.java: a sample client that reads from the socket and writes to standard output

```
package matchmaker;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ReaderClient {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ReaderClient.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ClientSocket client
                = new ClientSocket("localhost", 1234, "reader", "writer")) {
            Reader reader
                    = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            for (String s = in.readLine(); s != null; s = in.readLine()) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

WriterClient.java: a sample client that writes to the socket

```
package matchmaker;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class WriterClient {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ReaderClient.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ClientSocket client
                = new ClientSocket("localhost", 1234, "writer", "reader")) {
            Writer writer
                    = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
                out.println("Message line " + i);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The problem for me is. If the first connected client is identified in a new thread and the other client is identified too in another thread later. How can I connect these two? Maybe I create another thread that looks up an array where each socket and its id is saved after they connected and then connect the two clients as a seperate thread?

Comment: You don't need to create any thread until both parties are online. Except for the server thread (pool). In any case, you would need a global table, adequately protected, to do the matching.